# IMPORTJSON custom function google sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

```
/**
* Imports JSON data to your spreadsheet Ex: IMPORTJSON("http://myapisite.com","city/population")
* @param url URL of your JSON data as string
* @param xpath simplified xpath as string
* @customfunction
*/
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

I'm using this custom funcation in a  google sheet to try and import certain api data. I've gotten it to do some things but im having trouble getting it to pul the "id" from https://politicsandwar.com/api/alliances/   (this is in cell "a1")

In the cell in my sheet im using =importjson(A1, "alliances/id") but all it says is node not available.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reason of "Node Not Available" :

Data retrieved from `https://politicsandwar.com/api/alliances/` is JSON data. `alliances` is an array. When `for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){json = json[patharray[i]];}` is run by the inputted xpath `["alliances", "id"]`, I think that an error occurs at 2nd loop because of no `id` of the key in `json.alliances`. In your script, it seems that arrays in JSON cannot be analyzed.

#### Sample script :

If you want to retrieve data from `https://politicsandwar.com/api/alliances/` using `alliances/id`, the sample script only for doing it is as follows.

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var patharray = xpath.split("/");
  var res = [];
  for (var i in json[patharray[0]]) {
    res.push(json[patharray[0]][i][patharray[1]]);
  }
  return res;
}
```

If the display of data is not what you want, feel free to tell me. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.