# IMPORTJSON in Google Sheet sometimes not getting data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have created a sheet to keep my crypto holdings. I use this importJSON function I found on youtube : (I have changed the help text for myself)

```
/**
* Imports JSON data to your spreadsheet Ex: IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price")
* @param url URL of your JSON data as string
* @param xpath simplified xpath as string
* @customfunction
*/
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

I use this function to readout an API :
This is a piece of my script :

```
  var btc_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var btc_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B2").setValue([btc_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H2").setValue([btc_btc]);

  var bhc_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1831/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var bhc_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1831/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B3").setValue([bhc_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H3").setValue([bhc_btc]);
```

The last few days I get "Error getting data" errors. When I start manualy the script it works.

I than tried this code I found here :

[ImportJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696207/importjson-custom-function-google-sheets)

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var patharray = xpath.split("/");
  var res = [];
  for (var i in json[patharray[0]]) {
    res.push(json[patharray[0]][i][patharray[1]]);
  }
  return res;
}
```

But this gives an error about : TypeError: Cannot read property "quotes" from null. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is your script call API at least 4 times. When few users do it too, the Google server call API too much times.

The API of Coinmarketcap has limited bandwidth. When any client reach this limit, the API return [HTTP error 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). Google Scripts is on shared Google servers, that means lot of users looks as one client for Coinmarketcap API.

When API decline your request, your script fails – the error message corresponds to the assumed error (xpath cant find *quotes* component in empty varible).

**This is ruthless behavior. Please, don't ruin API via mass calls.**

You can load data from API at once and re-use it angain for each finding in data.

I have similar Spreadsheet automatically filled from Coinmarketcap API, you can copy it for your:

- [**Coins spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZTW3K1i-3YydGO1NCkKddIVHQPCty5xVIOPDi9HqPHg/edit)
- [**Google Script**](https://github.com/jakubboucek/google-script-coins-price-update/blob/master/Code.js) on GitHub.

This my script is strictly ask API only once for whole runtime and reusing one response for all queries.

### Change of your script

Also you can make few changes in your Code for saving resources:

Change `IMPORTJSON` function from this:

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
...
```

to this:

```
function IMPORTJSON(json, xpath) {
...
```

and rutime section of code you can change like this:

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=EUR");
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);

var btc_eur = IMPORTJSON(json,"data/quotes/EUR/price");
var btc_btc = IMPORTJSON(json,"data/quotes/BTC/price");
ss.getRange("B2").setValue([btc_eur]);
ss.getRange("H2").setValue([btc_btc]);
...
```

Main benefit is: the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is called only once.

Yes, I know, this code is not works 1:1 like your. That because that receive prices only for EUR and not for BTC. Naturally fetching comparation between BTC and BTC is unnecessary because it is always 1 and other values you can count matematically from EUR response – please don't abuse an api for such queries.

Answer (score 0):

As Jakub said, the main issue is that all requests are counted as coming from the same Google server.

One solution which I consider easier is to put a proxy server in the middle, this can be done by either purchasing a server and setting it up (which is quite complex) or using a service like Proxycrawl which includes some free requests and after that, unless you run thousands of queries per month, it should cost you less than 1 USD per month.

To do that you just need to edit one line of the script:

```js
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

This line, becomes this:

```js
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.proxycrawl.com/?token=YOUR_TOKEN&url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`);
```

**Make sure to replace YOUR_TOKEN with your actual service token**

Just this simple change will make the requests never fail as each request will be sent from a different IP instead of all coming from Google.