# importJSON in Google Sheet reduce API connections?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have made an other question here:

[First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565846/importjson-in-google-sheet-sometimes-not-getting-data.)

It seems I'm calling to much the API.

My script calls 23 times the API in one go.

This is how my script looks like :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Creates a menu called Crypto. 
function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Crypto')
      .addItem('Update Prices','updatePrices')
      .addItem('Update Sheet','updateSheet')
      .addToUi();

}

//Copy cells.
function copyCell() {

  ss.getRange("D2:D13").copyTo(ss.getRange("E2"), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("B2:B13").copyTo(ss.getRange("G2"), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("M1").copyTo(ss.getRange("M2"), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("M5").copyTo(ss.getRange("M6"), {contentsOnly:true});

}

/**
* Imports JSON data to your spreadsheet Ex: IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price")
* @param url URL of your JSON data as string
* @param xpath simplified xpath as string
* @customfunction
*/
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}


//Importing CMC Data into sheet
function importCMC() {

  var btc_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var btc_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B2").setValue([btc_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H2").setValue([btc_btc]);

  var bhc_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1831/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var bhc_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1831/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B3").setValue([bhc_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H3").setValue([bhc_btc]);

  var ltc_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var ltc_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B4").setValue([ltc_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H4").setValue([ltc_btc]);

  var ada_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2010/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var ada_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2010/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B5").setValue([ada_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H5").setValue([ada_btc]);

  var trx_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1958/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var trx_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1958/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B6").setValue([trx_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H6").setValue([trx_btc]);

  var neo_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1376/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var neo_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1376/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B7").setValue([neo_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H7").setValue([neo_btc]);

  var ont_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2566/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var ont_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2566/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B8").setValue([ont_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H8").setValue([ont_btc]);

  var gas_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1785/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var gas_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1785/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B9").setValue([gas_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H9").setValue([gas_btc]);

  var enj_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2130/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var enj_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2130/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B10").setValue([enj_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H10").setValue([enj_btc]);

  var tky_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2507/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var tky_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2507/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B11").setValue([tky_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H11").setValue([tky_btc]);

  var uuu_eur = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2645/?convert=EUR","data/quotes/EUR/price");
  var uuu_btc = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2645/?convert=BTC","data/quotes/BTC/price");
  ss.getRange("B12").setValue([uuu_eur]);
  ss.getRange("H12").setValue([uuu_btc]);

  var cmc_usd = IMPORTJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/global/","data/quotes/USD/total_market_cap");
  ss.getRange("M1").setValue([cmc_usd]);

}

//Getting euro prices from Coincapmarket and place them in specific cells.
function updatePrices() {

  copyCell();

  importCMC();

  //Get current date
  var now = new Date();
  ss.getRange('F1').setValue(now)

  }


//Getting euro prices from Coincapmarket and place them in specific cells.
function updateSheet() {

  copyCell();

  importCMC();

  //Get date.
  var now = new Date();
  ss.getRange('F1').setValue(now)

  ss.getRange("F1").copyTo((ss.getRange(ss.getRange("A18:A111").getValues().filter(String).length + 18, 1)), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("D15").copyTo((ss.getRange(ss.getRange("B18:B111").getValues().filter(String).length + 18, 2)), {contentsOnly:true});

  //Copy the formula's from row 19 to last filled cell in A and B.
  var row = 19;
  CopyFormulasDown.copyFormulasDown(ss, row);


}
```

The problem with V2 api of CMC is that the BTC price has to be checked with an other URL. I'm not a hero in array's. Sorry.

I'm thinking of pulling four times the ticker API and then find the right info

```
 1. https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=EUR
 2. https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=EUR&start=101
 3. https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=EUR&start=201 
 4. https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=EUR&start=301
```

Because the api limits to 100 tickers I have to create 4. I'm using V2 of the IP and I'm using the ID to get the right currency. That is the number behind the ticker. I have to use 4 downloads because The highest rank of currency is 316.

What is the best way to optimize this script with out calling to much api's?

Comment: Is the conversion between BTC and EUR changing between each of your calls? Seems like you could just find out that exchange rate once, and then fetch your ticker prices once, and just use math instead of an HTTP request to get its price in the other currency... Also, consider rewriting your use of IMPORTJSON to use `UrlfetchApp#fetchAll`. And, just because you aren't familiar with arrays, does not mean you are free to ignore them - you aren't. Learning the language is your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have reduced my script. It now has 4 api calls. Sometimes still to much for coinmarketcap.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Creates a menu called Crypto. 
function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Crypto')
      .addItem('Update Prices','updatePrices')
      .addItem('Update Sheet','updateSheet')
      .addToUi();

}

//Copy cells.
function copyCell() {

  ss.getRange("D2:D13").copyTo(ss.getRange("E2"), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("B2:B13").copyTo(ss.getRange("G2"), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("M1").copyTo(ss.getRange("M2"), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("M5").copyTo(ss.getRange("M6"), {contentsOnly:true});

}

//Importing CMC Data into sheet
function importCMC() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=EUR");
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);

  var btc_eur = json["data"]["1"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B2").setValue([btc_eur]);

  var bch_eur = json["data"]["1831"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B3").setValue([bch_eur]);

  var ltc_eur = json["data"]["2"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B4").setValue([ltc_eur]);

  var ada_eur = json["data"]["2010"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B5").setValue([ada_eur]);

  var trx_eur = json["data"]["1958"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B6").setValue([trx_eur]);

  var neo_eur = json["data"]["1376"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B7").setValue([neo_eur]);

  var ont_eur = json["data"]["2566"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B8").setValue([ont_eur]);

  var gas_eur = json["data"]["1785"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B9").setValue([gas_eur]);

  Utilities.sleep(5000)

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=EUR&start=101");
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);

  var enj_eur = json["data"]["2130"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B10").setValue([enj_eur]);

  var tky_eur = json["data"]["2507"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B11").setValue([tky_eur]);

  Utilities.sleep(5000)

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2645/?convert=EUR");
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var uuu_eur = json["data"]["quotes"]["EUR"]["price"];
  ss.getRange("B12").setValue([uuu_eur]);

  Utilities.sleep(5000)

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/global/");
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var cmc_usd = json["data"]["quotes"]["USD"]["total_market_cap"];
  ss.getRange("M1").setValue([cmc_usd]);

}


//Getting euro prices from Coincapmarket and place them in specific cells.
function updatePrices() {

  copyCell();

  importCMC();

  //Get current date
  var now = new Date();
  ss.getRange('F1').setValue(now)


}


//Getting euro prices from Coincapmarket and place them in specific cells.
function updateSheet() {

  copyCell();

  importCMC();

  //Get date.
  var now = new Date();
  ss.getRange('F1').setValue(now)

  ss.getRange("F1").copyTo((ss.getRange(ss.getRange("A18:A111").getValues().filter(String).length + 18, 1)), {contentsOnly:true});
  ss.getRange("D15").copyTo((ss.getRange(ss.getRange("B18:B111").getValues().filter(String).length + 18, 2)), {contentsOnly:true});

  //Copy the formula's from row 19 to last filled cell in A and B.
  var row = 19;
  CopyFormulasDown.copyFormulasDown(ss, row);


}
```